# When Singular Value and Eigenvalue are coincide

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values

For which matrix Singular Value and Eigenvalue are coincide?
I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2134144/do-eigenvalues-and-singular-values-of-a-symmetric-positive-definite-random-matr) question about it, but is their any definition for all the the matrix in with this group

Comment: A matrix's singular values and eigenvalues will coincide if and only if the matrix is symmetric (Hermitian) and positive definite

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks, for Positive Semi Definite it doesn't work? I think it do

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I believe Hermitian positive definite $\implies$ singular values = eigenvalues but I don't think the converse holds. Consider, for example, the zero matrix, whose eigenvalues and singular values clearly coincide.

Comment: about Positive Semi Definite https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162963/for-positive-semi-definite-matrices-each-singular-value-is-equal-to-eigenvalue